# Simulation in R

Tags: r

I need to simulate 100 datasets of n=100. I am trying something like:

```
x1 = NULL 
for (i in 1:100){
set.seed(i)
x1[i] <- sample(1:4, 100, replace=TRUE)
}
```

But I keep getting errors saying: 
 In x1[i] <- sample(1:4, 100, replace = TRUE) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

I am stumped. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Declare as a list and keep appending. `x1 <- list()`. And inside the loop `x1[[i]] <- sample(1:4, 100, replace=TRUE)`. Retrieve it using `x[[i]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the "replicate" function like this:

```
x1 <- replicate(100, sample(1:4,100,replace=T))
split(x1, col(x1))
```

If you are interested, there's an excellent ebook called "R Fundamentals & Graphics" for beginners in R.

Comment: Instead of `split`ting afterwards, "simplify = FALSE" in `replicate` could, also, be used.

Comment: Or you could let it simplify and index by row/column instead.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is change `x1[i]` to `x1[[i]]`

Paul

Comment: This will get the code to work but it's not the best way to do it.  You also didn't explain why this fixes the problem or why the initial attempt didn't work.

Comment: Well I am not the person who answered this and I am new to R but by looking at it, it is saving the 100 datasets as different lists and hence they need to be extracted by [[]] as opposed to [] for a vector which is why the code works. The initial attempt did not work because I was indexing by [i] instead of [[i]] which would be appropriate for a list in R.